# Javascript json to xlsx trello

Tags: javascript, trello

no soy experto en javascript pero estoy tratando de modificar una extensión que toma el json que exporta Trello y lo convierte a un formato de excel, la extensión funciona genial... pero me gustaría que también me extraiga la fecha de cada cards, que segun el json es "dateLastActivity:" pero se me complica entender el js de la extensión, aqui les dejo el github del js para q lo puedan ver [export for trello](https://github.com/llad/export-for-trello/blob/master/trelloexport.js)

```
//globals
    var $,
    byteString,
    xlsx,
    ArrayBuffer,
    Uint8Array,
    Blob,
    saveAs;


// Variables
var $excel_btn,
    addInterval,
    columnHeadings = ['List', 'Title', 'Description', 'Points', 'Due', 'Members', 'Labels', 'Card #', 'Card URL']; //aqui va las cabeceras del excel

window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

function createExcelExport() {
    "use strict";
    // RegEx to find the points for users of TrelloScrum
    var pointReg = /[\(](\x3f|\d*\.?\d+)([\)])\s?/m;

    var boardExportURL = $('a.js-export-json').attr('href');
    //RegEx to extract Board ID
    var parts = /\/b\/(\w{8})\.json/.exec(boardExportURL);

    if(!parts) {
        alert("Board menu not open.");
        return;
    }

    var idBoard = parts[1];
    var apiURL = "https://trello.com/1/boards/" + idBoard + "?lists=all&cards=all&card_attachments=cover&card_stickers=true&card_fields=badges%2Cclosed%2CdateLastActivity%2Cdesc%2CdescData%2Cdue%2CidAttachmentCover%2CidList%2CidBoard%2CidMembers%2CidShort%2Clabels%2CidLabels%2Cname%2Cpos%2CshortUrl%2CshortLink%2Csubscribed%2Curl&card_checklists=none&members=all&member_fields=fullName%2Cinitials%2CmemberType%2Cusername%2CavatarHash%2Cbio%2CbioData%2Cconfirmed%2Cproducts%2Curl%2Cstatus&membersInvited=all&membersInvited_fields=fullName%2Cinitials%2CmemberType%2Cusername%2CavatarHash%2Cbio%2CbioData%2Cconfirmed%2Cproducts%2Curl&checklists=none&organization=true&organization_fields=name%2CdisplayName%2Cdesc%2CdescData%2Curl%2Cwebsite%2Cprefs%2Cmemberships%2ClogoHash%2Cproducts&myPrefs=true&fields=name%2Cclosed%2CdateLastActivity%2CdateLastView%2CidOrganization%2Cprefs%2CshortLink%2CshortUrl%2Curl%2Cdesc%2CdescData%2Cinvitations%2Cinvited%2ClabelNames%2Cmemberships%2Cpinned%2CpowerUps%2Csubscribed";

    $.getJSON(apiURL, function (data) {

        var file = {
            worksheets: [[], []], // worksheets has one empty worksheet (array)
            creator: 'TrelloExport',
            created: new Date(),
            lastModifiedBy: 'TrelloExport',
            modified: new Date(),
            activeWorksheet: 0
        },

            // Setup the active list and cart worksheet
            w = file.worksheets[0],
            wArchived = file.worksheets[1],
            buffer,
            i,
            ia,
            blob,
            board_title;

        w.name = data.name.substring(0, 22);  // Over 22 chars causes Excel error, don't know why
        w.data = [];
        w.data.push([]);
        w.data[0] = columnHeadings;


        // Setup the archive list and cart worksheet
        wArchived.name = 'Archived ' + data.name.substring(0, 22);
        wArchived.data = [];
        wArchived.data.push([]);
        wArchived.data[0] = columnHeadings;

        // This iterates through each list and builds the dataset
        $.each(data.lists, function (key, list) {
            var list_id = list.id,
                listName = list.name;

            // tag archived lists
            if (list.closed) {
                listName = '[archived] ' + listName;
            }

            // Iterate through each card and transform data as needed
            $.each(data.cards, function (i, card) {
                if (card.idList === list_id) {
                    var title = card.name,
                        parsed = title.match(pointReg),
                        points = parsed ? parsed[1] : '',
                        due = card.due || '',
                        memberIDs,
                        memberInitials = [],
                        labels = [],
                        d = new Date(due),
                        rowData = [],
                        rArch,
                        r;

                    title = title.replace(pointReg, '');

                    // tag archived cards
                    if (card.closed) {
                        title = '[archived] ' + title;
                    }

                    memberIDs = card.idMembers;
                    $.each(memberIDs, function (i, memberID) {
                        $.each(data.members, function (key, member) {
                            if (member.id === memberID) {
                                memberInitials.push(member.initials);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    //Get all labels
                    $.each(card.labels, function (i, label) {
                        if (label.name) {
                            labels.push(label.name);
                        } else {
                            labels.push(label.color);
                        }

                    });

                    // Need to set dates to the Date type so xlsx.js sets the right datatype
                    if (due !== '') {
                        due = d;
                    }

                    rowData = [
                        listName,
                        title,
                        card.desc,
                        points,
                        due,
                        memberInitials.toString(),
                        labels.toString(),
                        card.idShort,
                        card.shortUrl
                    ];

                    // Writes all closed items to the Archived tab
                    // Note: Trello allows open cards on closed lists
                    if (list.closed || card.closed) {
                        rArch = wArchived.data.push([]) - 1;
                        wArchived.data[rArch] = rowData;

                    } else {
                        r = w.data.push([]) - 1;
                        w.data[r] = rowData;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        // We want just the base64 part of the output of xlsx.js
        // since we are not leveraging they standard transfer process.
        byteString = window.atob(xlsx(file).base64);
        buffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        ia = new Uint8Array(buffer);

        // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
        for (i = 0; i < byteString.length; i += 1) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        // create blob and save it using FileSaver.js
        blob = new Blob([ia], {
            type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        });
        board_title = data.name;
        saveAs(blob, board_title + '.xlsx');
        $("a.pop-over-header-close-btn")[0].click();


    });

}


// Add a Export Excel button to the DOM and trigger export if clicked
function addExportLink() {
    "use strict";
    //alert('add');

    var $js_btn = $('a.js-export-json'); // Export JSON link

    // See if our Export Excel is already there
    if ($('.pop-over-list').find('.js-export-excel').length) {
        clearInterval(addInterval);
        return;
    }

    // The new link/button
    if ($js_btn.length) {
        $excel_btn = $('<a>')
            .attr({
                'class': 'js-export-excel',
                'href': '#',
                'target': '_blank',
                'title': 'Open downloaded file with Excel'
            })
            .text('Exportar a Excel')
            .click(createExcelExport)
            .insertAfter($js_btn.parent())
            .wrap(document.createElement("li"));

    }
}


// on DOM load
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    // Look for clicks on the .js-share class, which is
    // the "Share, Print, Export..." link on the board header option list
    $(document).on('mouseup', ".js-share", function () {
        addInterval = setInterval(addExportLink, 500);
    });
});
```

pdt: basicamente la extension funciona de esta manera, cuanto entras a la configuracion del trello y la opcion de exportar solo te da la opcion de exportar como json, la extension modifica el dom y agrega una opcion mas que dice exportar en excel y genera el excel.

pdt2: para modificar una extension google no la reconocerá, recomiendo activar el modo desarrollador en administrador de extensiones, y en la opcion, 'cargar extension sin empaquetar' y agregan la carpeta que descarguen del github

tambien ire modificando de lograrlo lo compartire por aqui mismo... gracias de antemano y avisarme si infrinjo alguna norma para eliminar la pregunta... gracias

Comment: Bienvenido cual es tu pregunta o error ??

Comment: Que el js también exporte las fechas en el excel

Comment: @RaulCacacho ya logre hacerlo con pocas modificaciones, pero todas las columnas tienen poco ancho... js puede crear columnas con un ancho establecido? por que la columna de "descripcion" es muy delgada

Comment: Voy a investigar porque no estoy seguro como hacerlo

Comment: gracias, termino de modificar el codigo y lo publico, por otro lado la fecha que me da es de este formato "2017-10-27T23:01:29.752Z" hay manera de parsearlo o hacerlo mas amigable? gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno logre sacar las fechas modificando algunas lineas de código, solo me falta cambiar el formato de la fecha que me dan y cambiar el ancho de las celdas al exportar, pero ya cumple con el objetivo que deseaba... les dejo el código por si alguien pasa por lo mismo

```
/*!
 * TrelloExport
 * https://github.com/llad/export-for-trello
 *
 * Credit:
 * Started from: https://github.com/Q42/TrelloScrum
 */

/*jslint browser: true, devel: false*/

// Globals
var $,
    byteString,
    xlsx,
    ArrayBuffer,
    Uint8Array,
    Blob,
    saveAs;


// Variables
var $excel_btn,
    addInterval,
    columnHeadings = ['Lista', 'Titulo', 'Fecha', 'Participantes', 'Etiquetas', 'Cards N°', 'Card URL']; 

window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

function createExcelExport() {
    "use strict";
    // RegEx para encontrar los puntos para los usuarios de TrelloScrum
    var pointReg = /[\(](\x3f|\d*\.?\d+)([\)])\s?/m;

    var boardExportURL = $('a.js-export-json').attr('href');
    // RegEx para extraer la ID de la pizarra
    var parts = /\/b\/(\w{8})\.json/.exec(boardExportURL);

    if(!parts) {
        alert("Board menu not open.");
        return;
    }

    var idBoard = parts[1];
    var apiURL = "https://trello.com/1/boards/" + idBoard + "?lists=all&cards=all&card_attachments=cover&card_stickers=true&card_fields=badges%2Cclosed%2CdateLastActivity%2Cdesc%2CdescData%2Cdue%2CidAttachmentCover%2CidList%2CidBoard%2CidMembers%2CidShort%2Clabels%2CidLabels%2Cname%2Cpos%2CshortUrl%2CshortLink%2Csubscribed%2Curl&card_checklists=none&members=all&member_fields=fullName%2Cinitials%2CmemberType%2Cusername%2CavatarHash%2Cbio%2CbioData%2Cconfirmed%2Cproducts%2Curl%2Cstatus&membersInvited=all&membersInvited_fields=fullName%2Cinitials%2CmemberType%2Cusername%2CavatarHash%2Cbio%2CbioData%2Cconfirmed%2Cproducts%2Curl&checklists=none&organization=true&organization_fields=name%2CdisplayName%2Cdesc%2CdescData%2Curl%2Cwebsite%2Cprefs%2Cmemberships%2ClogoHash%2Cproducts&myPrefs=true&fields=name%2Cclosed%2CdateLastActivity%2CdateLastView%2CidOrganization%2Cprefs%2CshortLink%2CshortUrl%2Curl%2Cdesc%2CdescData%2Cinvitations%2Cinvited%2ClabelNames%2Cmemberships%2Cpinned%2CpowerUps%2Csubscribed";

    $.getJSON(apiURL, function (data) {

        var file = {
            worksheets: [[], []], // hojas de trabajo tiene una hoja de cálculo vacía (matriz)
            creator: 'TrelloExport',
            created: new Date(),
            lastModifiedBy: 'TrelloExport',
            modified: new Date(),
            activeWorksheet: 0
        },

            // Configurar la lista activa y la hoja de trabajo del carro
            w = file.worksheets[0],
            wArchived = file.worksheets[1],
            buffer,
            i,
            ia,
            blob,
            board_title;

        w.name = data.name.substring(0, 22);  // Más de 22 caracteres provoca un error de Excel, no sé por qué
        w.data = [];
        w.data.push([]);
        w.data[0] = columnHeadings;


        // Configurar la lista de archivos y la hoja de trabajo del carro
        wArchived.name = 'Archived ' + data.name.substring(0, 22);
        wArchived.data = [];
        wArchived.data.push([]);
        wArchived.data[0] = columnHeadings;

        // Esto itera a través de cada lista y crea el conjunto de datos
        $.each(data.lists, function (key, list) {
            var list_id = list.id,
                listName = list.name;

            // etiqueta de listas archivadas
            if (list.closed) {
                listName = '[archived] ' + listName;
            }

            // Itera a través de cada tarjeta y transforma los datos según sea necesario    
            $.each(data.cards, function (i, card) {
                if (card.idList === list_id) {
                    var title = card.name,
                        parsed = title.match(pointReg),
                        memberIDs,
                        memberInitials = [],
                        labels = [],
                        rowData = [],
                        rArch,
                        r;

                    title = title.replace(pointReg, '');

                    // tag archived cards
                    if (card.closed) {
                        title = '[archived] ' + title;
                    }

                    memberIDs = card.idMembers;
                    $.each(memberIDs, function (i, memberID) {
                        $.each(data.members, function (key, member) {
                            if (member.id === memberID) {
                                memberInitials.push(member.initials);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    //Get all labels
                    $.each(card.labels, function (i, label) {
                        if (label.name) {
                            labels.push(label.name);
                        } else {
                            labels.push(label.color);
                        }

                    });

                    // Necesita establecer fechas para el tipo de fecha para que xlsx.js establezca el tipo de datos correcto



                    rowData = [
                        listName,
                        title,
                        card.dateLastActivity,
                        memberInitials.toString(),
                        labels.toString(),
                        card.idShort,
                        card.shortUrl
                    ];

                    // Escribe todos los elementos cerrados en la pestaña Archivado
                    // Nota: Trello permite abrir tarjetas en listas cerradas
                    if (list.closed || card.closed) {
                        rArch = wArchived.data.push([]) - 1;
                        wArchived.data[rArch] = rowData;

                    } else {
                        r = w.data.push([]) - 1;
                        w.data[r] = rowData;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        // We want just the base64 part of the output of xlsx.js
        // since we are not leveraging they standard transfer process.
        byteString = window.atob(xlsx(file).base64);
        buffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        ia = new Uint8Array(buffer);

        // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
        for (i = 0; i < byteString.length; i += 1) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        // create blob and save it using FileSaver.js
        blob = new Blob([ia], {
            type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        });
        board_title = data.name;
        saveAs(blob, board_title + '.xlsx');
        $("a.pop-over-header-close-btn")[0].click();


    });

}


// Add a Export Excel button to the DOM and trigger export if clicked
function addExportLink() {
    "use strict";
    //alert('add');

    var $js_btn = $('a.js-export-json'); // Export JSON link

    // See if our Export Excel is already there
    if ($('.pop-over-list').find('.js-export-excel').length) {
        clearInterval(addInterval);
        return;
    }

    // The new link/button
    if ($js_btn.length) {
        $excel_btn = $('<a>')
            .attr({
                'class': 'js-export-excel',
                'href': '#',
                'target': '_blank',
                'title': 'Open downloaded file with Excel'
            })
            .text('Exportar a Excel')
            .click(createExcelExport)
            .insertAfter($js_btn.parent())
            .wrap(document.createElement("li"));

    }
}


// on DOM load
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    // Look for clicks on the .js-share class, which is
    // the "Share, Print, Export..." link on the board header option list
    $(document).on('mouseup', ".js-share", function () {
        addInterval = setInterval(addExportLink, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Que bueno que haya encontrado la solución. No olvide [aceptar su propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.